# Git svn clone creates empty repository

Tags: git, svn

I have a simple svn repository with one commit which is adding one file. Then I have another directory where I am trying to run git svn clone of that directory. But I get this output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ncantrel/gstest/trunk/.git/
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
git: 'svn' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    svn
```

Despite it not recognizing the command, it still creates a git repository with the name of the svn repository but its empty. I have also tried with the -s and -r commands and get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know which Linux version you are running, but quick googeling on the undefined symbol error brought this page up: http://jtes.net/2011/12/03/perl-perl_gthr_key_ptr-problems/

It states that "Fedora provides a number of prebuild perl libraries". Maybe your distro does that, too. The article suggests to use `cpan` to reinstall the needed library. Just type `sudo cpan` and then enter `force install SVN::Core`.

Hope this helps.